# terraform init fails - git must be available and on the PATH

Tags: git, terraform

I'm facing a problem when running terraform init / get.

Error I'm getting:

```
Error downloading modules: Error loading modules: error downloading 'ssh://git@github.com/etc etc': git must be available and on the PATH
```

The github path is correct, works fine on another machine.

Git works fine, it's in the PATH as well.
TF_LOGs are empty.
Working on ubuntu.

Thanks!

Comment: What OS are you running this from? You mention it works on Ubuntu but don't specify how you're running it when you get the failure. What does `git --version` show?

Answer (score 7):

I don't know if you solved your issue or not but I ran into the same problem and then solved it. Sharing the answer in case someone else needs help.

For reference I encountered this issue on

- Ubuntu 18.04
- Linux Ubuntu 4.15.0-45-generic
- Terraform v0.11.11 Rev 216 installed via Snap

The error comes from the file `terraform/vendor/github.com/hashicorp/go-getter/get_git.go` the `Get` function. The first thing that is attempted by the function is the following call

```
if _, err := exec.LookPath("git"); err != nil {
   return fmt.Errorf("git must be available and on the PATH")
}
```

This causes go to search all of the folders listed in path for a file with the supplied name, in this case `git`. I created and executed a go script that makes the same call and it behaved as expected, finding git without error.

After this I uninstalled terraform from snap and downloaded the executable straight from the Hashicorp website. When I ran that version of the executable which was still `v0.11.11` it ran without issue. This leads me to believe that the error has something to do with how snap was running the executable or the permission model around snap installed apps.

**TL;DR:** 
Uninstall the snap installed version of Terraform and instead download and use the Hashicorp binary.

Answer (score 2):

As per the [terraform documentation](https://www.terraform.io/docs/modules/sources.html#github),

For github.com projects, to clone over SSH, use the
   following form:

```
module "consul" {
  source = "git@github.com:hashicorp/example.git"
}
```

For Arbitrary Git repositories use the special git:: prefix

```
module "storage" {
  source = "git::ssh://username@example.com/storage.git"
}
```

Also, verify if Config `~/.ssh/config` is correct for your github account:

Hope this helps.

Comment: if its github its even simpler than you said its just:module "consul" {
  source = "github.com/hashicorp/example"
}

Answer (score 2):

Uninstall the **snap** installed version of **Terraform** and instead download and use the Hashicorp binary.

Answer (score 2):

I was on Windows and just launched my `terraform init` in Git Bash instead of the cmd and it worked.