# Unable to download modules from terraform registry

Tags: git, kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, terraform-provider-gcp

I tied to automate the gke cluster using terraform deafult module https://registry.terraform.io/modules/terraform-google-modules/kubernetes-engine/google/latest
But I'm getting the following error

Error: Failed to download module
│
│ Could not download module "gke" (maingk.tf:12) source code from
│ "github.com/terraform-google-modules/terraform-google-kubernetes-engine":
│ error downloading
│ 'https://github.com/terraform-google-modules/terraform-google-kubernetes-engine.git':
│ git must be available and on the PATH
╵

As per  [terraform init fails - git must be available and on the PATH](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54406076/terraform-init-fails-git-must-be-available-and-on-the-path/54990323)

I'm using the binary version of terraform and not the snap version. My version is 1.0.3. Not sure what is causing this issue? Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have `git` installed in the machine running the command, and add it to path.
If using Linux, this will do that for you `sudo apt-get install git`.